# Reduce many async Observable<List> into one Observable<List>

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

So here is what I'm trying to do:
for each event i want to call some `Service.getList()` 10 times, then merge the 10 lists into one.

Now I tried this two ways, they both work in UTs but fail in real app (I'm guessing I am not doing correctly the reduce operation given async http calls in real app).
For both cases I cannot see the logs put after `reduce()`, neither `onNext()` nor `onError()`, so I am guessing the `reduce()` operation does not complete.

Try #1:

```
public Observable<List<Event>> getEventsForLocation(Location location) {
List<Observable<List<Event>>> obs = new ArrayList<>();
for (Venue v : location.getVenues()) {
     obs.add(getEventsForVenue(v)); //does one http call, returns Observable<List<Event>> 
}
return Observable.concat(Observable.from(obs))
            .reduce((List<Event>) new ArrayList<Event>(), (events, events2) -> {
                events.addAll(events2);
                return events;
            })
            .doOnNext(events -> Log.d("reduce ", events.toString()))
            .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e("reduce error", throwable.toString()));}
```

Try #2:

```
public Observable<List<Event>> getEventsForLocation(Location location) {
return Observable
        .from(location.getVenues())
        .flatMap(venue -> getEventsForVenue(venue)) //does one http call, returns Observable<List<Event>> 
        .reduce((List<Event>) new ArrayList<Event>(), (events, events2) -> {
            events.addAll(events2);
            return events;
        })
       .doOnNext(events -> Log.d("service", "total events " + events.toString()))
       .doOnError(t -> Log.e("service", "total events error2 " + t.toString()));}
```

And the UT which passes for both approaches:

```
    @Test
    public void getEventsForLocation() {
        Location loc = new Location("test", newArrayList(new Venue("v1", "url1"),new Venue("v2", "url2")));

        when(httpGateway.downloadWebPage(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(
                Observable.just(readResource("eventsForVenue1.html")),
                Observable.just(readResource("eventsForVenue2.html"))
        );

        TestSubscriber<List<Event>> probe = new TestSubscriber<>();
        service.getEventsForLocation(loc).subscribe(probe);

        probe.assertNoErrors();

        //assert the next event containts contents of all lists
        List<Event> events = probe.getOnNextEvents().get(0);

        //first list
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected title", "event1", events.get(0).getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected artist", "artist1", events.get(0).getArtist());
        //second list
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected title", "event2", events.get(1).getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected artist", "artist2", events.get(1).getArtist());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the more complete code, with the schedulers.

```
Observable
                .just(loc)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(location -> service.getEventsForLocation(location))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(getObserver();
```

Comment: What's the failure? Does your real app do the network call. Did you apply subscribeOn/observeOn?

Comment: As i said there is no exception, just that i think the reduce somehow does not create any output, its still waiting for elements to merge. I think this because the logs put after it don;t happen. The subscription in created, I know this because if i put logs before of reduce, they will be printed. I also applied subscribeOn/observeOn.

Comment: I just discovered this: It is a bad idea to use reduce to collect emitted items into a mutable data structure. Instead, use collect for that purpose.  Did not get the change to try it yet.

Comment: The reason UT is passing its because it executes on only 1 scheduler, while the real app executes in different schedulers. I have to update the UT to simulate the different schedulers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the final order in the list, you can just use `from` + `flatMap` + `flatMapIterable` + `toList`:

```
Observable.from(location.getVenues())
.flatMap(venue -> getEventsForVenue(venue))
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
.toList();
```

If order matters and you want to execute getEventsForVenue in "parallel", you can replace flatMap with concatMapEager:

```
Observable.from(location.getVenues())
.concatMapEager(venue -> getEventsForVenue(venue))
.concatMapIterable(list -> list)
.toList();
```

Comment: I've tried both of your solutions, they both work in the UTs but in the real app they've got the same problem that I had with my original solutions, they hang, meaning they never return values.

Comment: How is your `getEventsForVenue()` implemented? It might never complete or the whole thing fails but you don't consume errors when you subscribe().

Comment: public Observable<List<Event>> getEventsForVenue(Venue venue) {
        return httpGateway.downloadWebPage(venue.getUrl())
                .map(data -> parser.parseEvents(data))
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());
    }  

also when subscribing, i always pass an error handler for onError

Comment: In this case, you have to go debugging via doOnEach to see where signals stop.

Comment: I discovered i was not completing the many async streams, so probably that is why it hangs. I will test your solutions again and get back to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collect and it will do the trick. But in this scenarios where I´m merging severals items, normally I much rather use Scan. Which for every new item it will give you the last processed item. So you can append every item with the previous items.

Take a look the marble diagram in case is suitable for your case
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html

Try to start with this simple example and then try to apply it into your code

```
/**
 * apply this function for every item against the previous emitted item from the source.
 *  Emitted:
            0
            1
            3
            6
            10
            15
 */
@Test
public void scanObservable() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Observable.from(numbers)
              .scan((lastItemEmitted, newItem) -> (lastItemEmitted + newItem))
              .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I replaced reduce() with collect() but it still does not work. I can see the logs just before collect() but no logs after collect() meaning it does not complete to send the final event. I also placed logs in collect() which i also see

Comment: Difficult to say without see those logs. I would recommend you do a first iteration with the most simple scenario with the structure that you want to achieve. Then make it more and more complex

Comment: i don't need scan() because i don't need the accumulated item for each event. i just want the last value, containing the whole (value 15 from your example)

Comment: Ok, I though that you wanted merge all the list emitted

Answer (score 0):

I finally found one solution, using zip() but i don't like it.
The problem should be able to be resolved with a combination of flatMap/reduce

```
public Observable<List<Event>> getEventsForLocation(Location location) {
        List<Observable<List<Event>>> venues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Venue v : location.getVenues()) {
            venues.add(Observable.just(v).flatMap(venue -> getEventsForVenue(venue)));
        }
        return Observable.zip(venues, new FuncN<List<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Event> call(Object... args) {
                List<Event> allEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
                for (Object o : args) {
                    List<Event> le = (List<Event>) o;
                    allEvents.addAll(le);
                }
                return allEvents;
            }
        });
```